# esp32 rgb led matrix dma

Tags: rgb, esp32, led

I simply want to display C85 on 64x32 rgb led matrix with hub75 interface. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDNNi.jpg)
but there is two blank line horizontal coming up.
I tried to customized the default pin also but it is not working. Please help me to resolve this.

below is my code which display as per image.

```
#include <ESP32-HUB75-MatrixPanel-I2S-DMA.h> 
#define R1_PIN_DEFAULT  25
#define G1_PIN_DEFAULT  26
#define B1_PIN_DEFAULT  27
#define R2_PIN_DEFAULT  14
#define G2_PIN_DEFAULT  12
#define B2_PIN_DEFAULT  13

#define A_PIN_DEFAULT   23
#define B_PIN_DEFAULT   19
#define C_PIN_DEFAULT   5
#define D_PIN_DEFAULT   17
#define E_PIN_DEFAULT   -1 // IMPORTANT: Change to a valid pin if using a 64x64px panel.
            
#define LAT_PIN_DEFAULT 4
#define OE_PIN_DEFAULT  15
#define CLK_PIN_DEFAULT 16

#define PANEL_RES_X 64      // Number of pixels wide of each INDIVIDUAL panel module. 
#define PANEL_RES_Y 32     // Number of pixels tall of each INDIVIDUAL panel module.
#define PANEL_CHAIN 1      // Total number of panels chained one to another

MatrixPanel_I2S_DMA *dma_display = nullptr;

uint16_t myRED = dma_display->color565(255, 0, 0);

void setup() {
    HUB75_I2S_CFG mxconfig(
    PANEL_RES_X,   // module width
    PANEL_RES_Y,   // module height
    PANEL_CHAIN    // Chain length
  );

  mxconfig.clkphase = false;
  mxconfig.driver = HUB75_I2S_CFG::FM6126A;
  dma_display = new MatrixPanel_I2S_DMA(mxconfig);
  dma_display->begin();
  dma_display->setBrightness8(60); //0-255
  dma_display->clearScreen(); 

  dma_display->fillScreenRGB888(0, 0, 200);
  dma_display->setTextSize(2);     // size 1 == 8 pixels high
  dma_display->setTextWrap(false); 
  dma_display->setTextColor(myRED);
  dma_display->setCursor(7,11);   
  dma_display->println("C85");
 
}

void loop() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you pass your pin config to the display setup?

Try modifying the display initialization like this:

```
  HUB75_I2S_CFG::i2s_pins _pins={R1, G1, BL1, R2, G2, BL2, CH_A, CH_B, CH_C, CH_D, CH_E, LAT, OE, CLK};
  HUB75_I2S_CFG mxconfig(
    PANEL_RES_X,   // module width
    PANEL_RES_Y,   // module height
    PANEL_CHAIN,   // Chain length
    _pins;
  );
```

by defining define these "R1, G1, BL1, R2, G2, BL2, CH_A, CH_B, CH_C, CH_D, CH_E, LAT, OE, CLK" according to your pin out or use your defines instead.